# How can I find an item's place in a list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, list, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm trying to define an instance method to find an item's place in a list. The list is `Thing.all.order(:hardness).reverse`. The item's place in the list should be the value of `def rank`. So for example, the "Thing" with the third highest 'hardness' should have a `rank` value of 3.

Here's what I started:

```
def rank
  Thing.all.order(:hardness).reverse.each_with_index 
  .....
end
```

But I'm drawing a blank on how to finish it. Am I at least on the right track?

---

```
def hardness
  self.defeats - self.wins
end
```

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: Sqlite3. BroiSatse gave an excellent suggestion, but now I just need to figure out how implement it if `hardness` is an instance method, not a database column.

Comment: Hum.. So if you want to implement a method... Which column you would like to use to calculate the rank.. ?

Comment: I'm not using a column. My model `thing` has a method named `hardness`, and I want to check how many `things` have a higher `hardness` value than the current thing.

Comment: @JoeMorano - Even though you can do that, it will be extremely inefficient as you would have to load all the models from the database and then loop over them. How is hardness method defined?

Comment: Shown the definition of win and defeat method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't that be easier to count all harder records instead?

```
def rank
  self.class.where('hardness > ?', self.hardness).count + 1
end
```

All depends on how do you want to treat items with the same hardness.

Comment: Haha that's genius. I would have never have come up with that. Thanks!

Comment: What if hardness is an instance method not a column?